# What is the best way to reliable store a complex Java object hierarcy?

Tags: java, json, serialization, configuration, persistence

I'm currently developing a software where the user can define a complex hierarchy of objects as settings. 
Also this settings objects will provide interfaces as an API for other developers.
Now I want to store these setting and reload it.

I'm  currently considering different ways to do exactly that, but none of my solutions are "good" in my opinion.

**The main goals should be:**

1. It should **output a String**, because i prefer a human readable configuration over a fast one.
2. It should be **reliable** even when the the **code is changing**. This means not it should do magic, but it should be obvious that an change could break already stored configuration. (Eg. How do I prevent that my colleague renaming a class and breaking production. )
3. Storing and loading should work with o**bject, interfaces and generics**.
4. Keep configuration of what is stored how as low as possible. I would prefer **convention over configuration**.

I know many of you faced the same or a similar issue while developing.

**So what was your solution? Which framework did you use and why?**

All solutions I came up with are either not reliant, a huge configuration or to much code.

So I'm looking forward to get some good new perspectives on this topic from all of you.

Thanks.

Comment: `none of my solutions are "good" in my opinion` for eg?

Comment: Eg. Using Gson, Serialization, Writing an own persistence Interface that hast manually be implemented, using Annotations to mark and parse classes ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For further information this how i solved this problem now:

I used Gson for serializing the object hierarchy to JSON. Added an Generic TypeAdapter to it for serializing and  deserializing all known Interfaces. This adapter saves the class name into the JSON object and constructs this class while deserializing. No additional configuration is needed, besides registering this TypeAdapter for each used Interface.

In order to make it reliable I will add an Unit Test to the project that will deserialize the complete possible configuration. So any changes to the code will break the tests.

In this way i can fulfill all of the points mentioned above.

I hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to specify a XSD and use JAXB to generate the Java classes and marshal and unmarshal XML based settings files.

Make sure the root tag contains the version of the XSD. You can use StAX to read the version first and determine the correct version of JAXB classes if you need to support several versions.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [XStream](http://x-stream.github.io/). Without any configuration it has similar capabilities as `java.io.*ObjectStream` but outputs XML instead of binary blob. You will only want to add few aliases for class names to make file more readable.